# Why binding to context is necessary in Werkzeug

Tags: python, python-2.7, werkzeug

I was reading the source code of the [Werkzeug](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug) library in github and in one of the examples ([Simplewiki](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/examples/simplewiki) to name it), in the `application.py` file there is function which binds the application to the current active context. I would like to know why this is necessary, or where can I find something that explains this?

The function is this:

```
def bind_to_context(self):
        """
        Useful for the shell.  Binds the application to the current active
        context.  It's automatically called by the shell command.
        """
        local.application = self
```

And this is the part where the dispatcher binds the request.

```
def dispatch_request(self, environ, start_response):
        """Dispatch an incoming request."""
        # set up all the stuff we want to have for this request.  That is
        # creating a request object, propagating the application to the
        # current context and instanciating the database session.
        self.bind_to_context()
        request = Request(environ)
        request.bind_to_context()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `contexts` in the `Werkzeug` is about separating environment between different threads. For example, contexts are very common thing in the `Flask` framework which is built on top of the `Werkzeug`. You can run Flask application in multi-threaded mode. In such case you'll have only one application object which is accessed by multiple threads simultaneously. Each thread requires a piece of data within the app for private usage. Storing such data is organized via [thread's local storage](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.local). And this is called the context.